# How can I remove Wordpress or other theme branding from the footer of my website

Tags: javascript, themes

I see with every installed theme there is a part on the footer. How can I remove Wordpress or other theme branding from the footer of my website?

Edit 3:

For those who think this is not we should not remove this: Based on the license it is possible to remove the branding or make any changes that you wish.
Find more information here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/remove-proudly-powered-by-wordpress-footer-link/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @N.Ivanov Based on the Wordpress license, we can make any necessary changes to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good tutorial for this in https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/remove-proudly-powered-by-wordpress-footer-link/

The quickest and easiest way to remove the footer credit is to add some CSS to the Theme Customizer. To do this:

1- Go to Appearance > Customize in the WordPress admin

2- Click Additional CSS at the bottom of the menu, and

3- Paste in the CSS code below.

```
.site-info { display: none; }
```